# How do I swap two groups of lines in a .sql file?

Tags: text-processing

I have a dump file with various `INSERT` statements.  The file looks something like

```
start_lines

INSERT INTO table1234 …
INSERT INTO table1234 …
INSERT INTO table1234 …

INSERT INTO table7890 …
INSERT INTO table7890 …
INSERT INTO table7890 …

 end_lines
```

I need all the `INSERT INTO table7890` statements to go above the `INSERT INTO table1234` statements.  I would like to keep all the `start_lines` and `end_lines` in the same position they were before the switch occurs.  So, for instance, if the `start_lines` occupy lines 3 through 18, after switching the insert statements, they should continue to appear 3 through 18.  Ditto for the end lines.

How do I switch the groups of statements ?

Comment: Bash is not a standard text editor; there are text processing tools to do that job, like perl, awk, sed, etc.

Comment: Make sure your sample data is representative -- one line per insert, only two table names?

Comment: Maybe you need to provide some more details on what you want to do, because as the question is expressed right now a single answer could be use `tac file` command (reverse read the file, opposite to `cat`)

Comment: Yeah good call.  I added some clarification.  I want to switch those INSERT INTO statements in the file, but I want all the other lines in the file to remain right where they are.

Comment: The more details you add, the more it seems like you want a script that will do things based on some obscure (possibly unneeded) logic that is known only to your brain.  Your specs can not be applied as you seem to expect and you'll always get another case and another case where your mind will say "oh and I'd prefer if it did this instead of that on those lines."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simplistic approach is to read the file twice, 1st time you save the paragraphs and 2nd time your swap them e.g. with `awk` (in paragraph mode):

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR{
if (/table1234/) {one=$0} else if (/table7890/){two=$0}
next
}
{
if (/table1234/) {$0=two} else if (/table7890/){$0=one}
}
1' infile infile
```

This will print a trailing empty line, if it matters...

---

Another way with ol' `ed` which does work in this particular case:

```
ed -s infile <<\IN
g/INSERT INTO table1234/d
-1r !grep -F 'INSERT INTO table7890' infile
+1,$g/INSERT INTO table7890/d
-1r !grep -F 'INSERT INTO table1234' infile
,p
q
IN
```

Comment: Your first solution caused a "awk(12770,0x7fffc50f43c0) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071562969088) failed (error code=3)" error but the second solution ran like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it but the simplest I can see is with `grep`:

```
grep -v table1234 test.sql; grep table1234 test.sql
```

You start by outputting everything except `table1234` lines, and after you only output `table1234` lines.

If you want, you can also redirect it to a new file:

```
(grep -v table1234 test.sql; grep table1234 test.sql) > test2.sql
```

Comment: How does this move the lines "INSERT INTO table7890" above the "INSERT INTO table1234" lines?  Your line, "grep -v table1234 test.sql; grep table1234 test.sql" doesn't reference "table7890".

Comment: @Dave: It makes all table1234 operations go at the end.  It probably doesn't match your latest update which makes very little sense to me since the inserts are totally independent from each other.  How can you expect independent things to take the same amount of space?

Comment: I originally thought you had a good reason like constraints that depended on other tables to be populated before table1234 but if that's not your issue, you should really think it through.

Comment: It is indeed to avoid foreign key errors.  I need the "INSERT INTO table7890" statements to go above the "INSERT INTO table1234" statements to avoid foreign key errors.  But if the "INSERT INTO table7890" go directly to the end of the ifle it will cause foreign key errors with the lines that occur after the "INSERT INTO table7890" statements.

Comment: Did you even try running my command to see if it would solve your problem or not?  If it still has an issue, mention what the issue is precisely.

Comment: I did and it does move the lines to the end of the file.  Unfortunately that leaves me with other foreign key errors when I run my script because I need the lines to be below "INSERT INTO table7890" but above the lines that follow "INSERT INTO table7890".

Comment: Are these two consecutive?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What does "two" refer to?

Comment: The inserts from the two tables you mention clearly.  Are they consecutive or do they have others in between?